# What is the Taylor series expansion of $\frac{2z+1}{(z+1)^2}$ at $z=i$

Tags: complex-analysis

> What is the Taylor series expansion of $\frac{2z+1}{(z+1)^2}$ at $z=i$?

I try to use that $a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(i)}{n!}$, but the formula is too tedious. How should I proceed?

Comment: Set $z=i+w$ and expand $$\frac{1+2i+2w}{(1+i+w)^2}=\frac{1+2i}{(1+i)^2}\frac{1+\frac{2w}{1+2i}}{\left(1+\frac{w}{1+i}\right)^2}$$ into powers of $w$. This requires only to know that, when $u\to0$, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nu^{n-1}=\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty u^n\right)'=\left(\frac1{1-u}\right)'=\frac{1}{(1-u)^2}$$

Comment: Why do you want $1+\frac{2w}{1+2i}$ on the denominator? @Did

Comment: To expand more easily the function into a power series in $w$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are looking for a representation
\begin{align*}
  \frac{2z+1}{(z+1)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-i)^n\qquad\qquad a_n\in\mathbb{C}
  \end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{2z+1}{(z+1)^2}&=\frac{2(z-i)+(1+2i)}{((z-i)+(1+i))^2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{(1+i)^2}\cdot\frac{2(z-i)+(1+2i)}{\left(1+\frac{z-i}{1+i}\right)^2}\\
>   &=-\frac{i}{2}\left(2(z-i)+(1+2i)\right)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-2}{n}\left(\frac{z-i}{1+i}\right)^n\tag{1}\\
>   &=\left(-i(z-i)+\left(1-\frac{1}{2}i\right)\right)
>   \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)(-1)^n\left(\frac{z-i}{1+i}\right)^n\tag{2}\\
>   &=-i\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(n+1)(-1)^n}{(1+i)^n}(z-i)^{n+1}\\
>   &\qquad +\left(1-\frac{1}{2}i\right)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(n+1)(-1)^n}{(1+i)^n}(z-i)^n\tag{3}\\
>   &=-i\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n(-1)^{n-1}}{(1+i)^{n-1}}(z-i)^{n}\\
>   &\qquad + \left(1-\frac{1}{2}i\right)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(n+1)(-1)^n}{(1+i)^n}(z-i)^n\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}(n-1)i}{(1+i)^n}(-1)^n(z-i)^n+1-\frac{1}{2}i\tag{5}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}(-1+i)^n\left(1+\frac{1}{2}(n-1)i\right)(z-i)^n
> \qquad\qquad\quad |z-i|<\sqrt{2}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we expand the *[binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* at $z=i$ with radius of convergence $\left|\frac{z-i}{1+i}\right|<1$, i.e. $|z-i|<\sqrt{2}$.
- In (2) we apply the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (3) we rearrange the series according to powers of $z-i$.
- In (4) shift the index of the left series by one to obtain powers $(z-i)^n$.
- In (5) we collect the terms with equal powers.
- In (6) we do some final simplifications.